# Cannot display twitter feed in Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to make an app that parses data from Twitter using `JSON` and get the live twitter feed, I was successfully able to log the data into the logcat, but somehow I am unable to display the same in the `ListView`, the last news feed is showing up in the `ListView` but the rest of feeds are gone. I add them in an `Arraylist` before using an `ArrayAdapter` to do so.What is wrong with my code, am I parsing the `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` correctly or is there any conversion that I am missing?

```
public class readingtwitterfeedsActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String readTwitterFeed = readTwitterFeed();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readTwitterFeed);
        Log.i(readingtwitterfeedsActivity.class.getName(),
                "Number of entries " + jsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i(readingtwitterfeedsActivity.class.getName(),   jsonObject.getString("text"));
            List<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
            al.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  public String readTwitterFeed() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
            "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/bbcnews.json");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(readingtwitterfeedsActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just initializing the string array before the for loop and set adapter after completion of for loop..**

Try this, replace in your code.

```
List<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i(readingtwitterfeedsActivity.class.getName(),   jsonObject.getString("text"));

            al.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));

        }
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: why is that the case that if we initialize the arraylist within the for loop this thing doesn't work?

Comment: At every time new Arraylist will be initialized and you add item at that new arraylist. So the last arraylist will replace other. And set only last arraylist with only one last item. If you found this answer as correct then please upvote it and accept as a correct anser by (click on right symbol below voting button left side of answer). this will help you and other user also.